# excel formula how to build similarity matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, similarity

I would like to create a formula that will create a similarity matrix from a table of data.  Here is an example of the data followed by the desired output.  The rows of data represent the result of a modularity class algorithm.  I need my output to calculate the number of months two countries share the same class value (It can be any value as long as they are equal) divided by the number of total months.

Input modularity class

```
        jan feb mar apr may
USA     0   1   2   4   3
UK      0   3   2   3   3
AU      0   2   2   2   3
CH      1   0   1   1   2
EG      2   3   0   0   1
```

Output similarity matrix

```
      USA   UK   AU  CH  EG
USA   1             
UK   0.6    1           
AU   0.6    0.6  1      
CH    0     0    0    1 
EG    0     0.2  0    0   1
```

I have not tried any formula because I dont understand where to begin.  I have read about countifs and mmult, but I dont know what is most appropriate.

Comment: Do you know where the .6 in first column, second row comes from? Would it be that the UK shares 3 of 5 months (3/5 = .6) with the US, that is, Jan, Mar, and May? I'm hoping that this would give you a place to begin.

Comment: Yes rajah9.  That is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, there is a way using `SUM()`, `IF()`, `COUNT()` and using array formulas.

The basic formula that you could use is (assuming your top array is `A1:F6`, including the headers, so the data is in `A2:F6`):

```
{=SUM(IF($B$2:$F$2=$B2:$F2,1,0))/COUNT($B$2:$F$2)}
```

Using array formulas, you can make the `IF()` function return 1 for a match, and 0 for a mismatch, iterating through each element in a row.  `SUM()` adds the matches up, and then dividing by the `COUNT()` of the number of cells processed gives you your similarity index.

The example above is for the top USA/USA cell in your example, you can fill down with that, but each new diagonal needs adjusting to change the fixed row number to the new row.  So the top of the UK column would be:

```
{=SUM(IF($B$3:$F$3=$B3:$F3,1,0))/COUNT($B$3:$F$3)}
```

[image: Conditional sum using array formulas]

The `COUNT()` could be removed if you know how many columns/countries there are in advance.

**Note:** You do not type the curly braces.  When you have finished entering the formula you ***have*** to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> whilst editing, to get those to appear and for the formula to be treated as an array formula.  These formulas are often called *CSE formulas* for this reason (Ctrl-Shift-Enter).

**Update:**

You can do it with a single formula, filled over the cells, using `INDIRECT()` and `COLUMN()` as well.

```
{=SUM(IF(INDIRECT("$B$"&COLUMN(B2)):INDIRECT("$F$"&COLUMN(B2))=$B2:$F2,1,0))/COUNT(INDIRECT("$B$"&COLUMN(B2)):INDIRECT("$F$"&COLUMN(B2)))}
```

This uses the fact that the column number is the same as the row number, providing the transposition.

**Update 2:**

Actually, the `COUNT()` can be eliminated and `SUM()` replaced with `AVERAGE()` as all matches are 1, the mean is the correct value.

So this works for all cells:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(INDIRECT("$B$"&COLUMN(B2)):INDIRECT("$F$"&COLUMN(B2))=$B2:$F2,1,0))}
```

**Update 3:**

If you desparately need nothing to appear on the upper diagonal side, making a lower triangular block, then you can use an `IF()` wrapping the above formula, checking to see if the column is greater than the row and making the cell blank in that case.  You can then fill the entire block with the formula and it will look right, with no need for deleting.

```
{=IF(COLUMN(B2)>ROW(B2),"",AVERAGE(IF(INDIRECT("$B$"&COLUMN(B2)):INDIRECT("$F$"&COLUMN(B2))=$B2:$F2,1,0)))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the CSE reference. You taught me something new about Excel.

Comment: Thank you both.  I think this will suffice.  @rajah9, I dont understand dividing by the row total, because then I am adding (for UK) the USA, AU, and EG counts together for my 0.6 and I am trying to get a 1:1 association country to country.   Regardless, you've both helped immensely.  Thanks again.

Comment: @rajah9: CSE (array formulas) are a very powerful part of Excel, I've not long been using them myself - despite using and teaching Excel for nearly 20 years!  Most people find them too fiddly to apply or two complicated to understand and thus they are underused and poorly documented.

Comment: @lphantgirl: What did you not understand about the division by the total?  The `SUM()` gives the number of matches, the `COUNT()` gives the number of columns (countries) being considered.  The division is the ratio, which is the similarity index.  The `COUNT()` is always 5 in your example data above.

Comment: @Orbling: Thanks for the update!  You are helping a PhD student and I thank you.  This forum has been so helpful in my python code that I was hoping I might find an excel guru as well.  :)

Comment: @lphantgirl: You can actually use the `AVERAGE()` formula instead, have added another update to show this.

Comment: @lphantgirl: Excel is not my usual home ground, but have been using it quite a lot lately.  Am answering a few of the more complex Excel questions when I'm bored, mainly to advance my own skill.  Nothing like a tangible exemplar case to learn a new technique.  Good luck with your research/thesis.

Comment: @rajah9: I think the confusion comes from your labels in the country names USA .. EG in B10:F10.  You say that the numbers are the months that UK=USA, but the column names are USA to EG not months.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to provide a nudge in the right direction, rather than the whole solution. I think you'll be able to generalize the solution from the formulas given.

I placed your input matrix in A1:F6. Then I set up an intermediate matrix. A9 is simply "Matches in column 1."

===edit: Using month names in columns ===

Then I copied the month names jan .. may in B10:F10. Also USA .. EG in A11 .. A15.

Then in B12, the fun starts. I put a formula, `=IF(B3=B2,1,0)`. What this does is it places a 1 in the cell if B3=B2, or a 0 otherwise. Then I fill right from B12 to F12 and I get the following row calculated:

```
1   0   1   0   1
```

You will note that these are the months when UK = USA.

If you take B12 and fill down to B15 and then fill B12 .. B15 right to F15, you will get the difference between each country and its adjacent neighbor. My matrix turned out to be:

```
    jan feb mar apr may
USA                 
UK  1   0   1   0   1
AU  1   0   1   0   1
CH  0   0   0   0   0
EG  0   0   0   0   0
```

If you divide the sum of the rows by the number of countries, you will get 3/5, 3/5, 0/5, 0/5. These correspond to the output matrix of your first column, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0.

Comment: One extra table per country at that rate.

Comment: Agreed, @Orbling, which is why I called it a nudge. If I gave the OP a very fancy formula with combinations of absolute and relative references, I would rob her of the joy of discovery.

Comment: @Iphantgirl  Yes, I sorry about the confusion. The column titles across the top would be better left as jan .. may. (I was trying to get an intermediate step between your input and output tables, but you are right: It should be a comparison between Jan US and Jan UK.) I will edit my answer, for clarity, but I'm sure you can Orbling's full answer right away.

Comment: Generally this method is pretty much the only way if you don't cheat with the array formulas.